# Diffraction pattern of X-ray and electron

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, diffraction, wave-particle-duality, x-rays

Electron diffraction is used to study about wave - particle duality of matter. A beam of electrons directed at a single crystal produced a diffraction pattern like an X-ray diffraction pattern.

I have questions regarding that:

1. Why X-ray does produce ring-shaped diffraction pattern?
2. Why do we compare electron diffraction pattern to X-ray diffraction pattern when studying about wave-particle duality of matter?

Thank you

Comment: For a single crystal, x-rays don’t create circles or rings for the diffraction pattern, so your question is unclear.

Comment: I think I should change "single crystal" to "thin metal foil". Is it good now?

Comment: Sorry, another question? What will the diffraction pattern be if X ray is directed to single crystal?

Comment: Polycrystalline or powder sample, fine. Now, what do you know about diffraction? I suspect Wikipedia has stuff to say about single vs polycrystalline patterns.

Comment: I will take a look

Answer (score -1):

I will leave the xray difraction pattern for others.

I want to clear up this :

> 2.Why do we compare electron diffraction pattern to X-ray diffraction pattern when studying about wave-particle duality of matter?

The simplest electron diffraction pattern is the [double slit experiment one electron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) at a  time.

[image: dblsl]

> electron built up over time

We see how the probability wavelike nature is built up by individual hits of electrons

This can be compared with a double slit experiment [one photon at a time:](https://www.sps.ch/en/articles/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/)

[image: photdoubleslit]

So when treating electrons and photons one at a time, the diffraction pattern appears in the probability of finding the particle at the (x,y) of the screen.

It so happens that light (zillion of photons) shows the same interference pattern as single photon accumulation. It is a mathematical effect that is based on the maxwell equations.

The wave nature of the electron  appears only when single electrons traverse matter. What waves is the pobability, not the energy of mass of the electron.

Light being a superposition of zillions of photons displays the diffraction pattern of energy waves going through a medium .